# 301 Redirect Links to Use .html Suffix

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I'm wondering how I could 301 redirect all urls of the format

```
/search/(.*)
```

(where `(.*)` is not terminated by .html)

to

```
/search/$1.html
```

Mainly I'm just not quite sure how I can match the url structure not having .html at the end, that's my issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `%{REQUEST_URI}` as a condition to negatively match against it, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/search/([^.]+)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ /search/$1.html [R=302,NC,L]
```

*I've used `302` in my above example, simple because when testing I always use 302 to make sure its working so I don't get cached, once you confirm its working, you can safely switch it to `[R=301,NC,L]`.*

In other words, if the URL is not `search/something.html` it will redirect to its version with the ending `.html`.

NOTE: Keep in mind that the order where you place this rule and your system/CMS if any can affect the result you get. If you had previously tried 301 redirects you might also be cached and it will as well affect the results.